# In which precedence is this statement evaluated?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, associativity

```
++*P--;
```

That is a question from an exam, if `P` a pointer to any element in an array, explain what this statement really does.

I even wrote a simple code to evaluate it:

```
  int i;
    int* array = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
        printf("%d,", array[i]);
    }
    int* P = array + 5;
    printf("\n %p", P);
    printf("\n %d", *P);

    ++*P--;
    printf("\n %p", P);
    printf("\n %d \n", *P);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d,", array[i]);
    }
```

But the output confuses me even more:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
 0x100105534
 5
 0x100105530
 4 
0,1,2,3,4,6,6,7,8,9,
```

It looks like it first dereferences `P`, then increases its value and then decreases value of pointer `P`, but why?

According to K&R table 2-1 from p53 (see the picture below)
++, --, and * (dereference) has the same precedence and associativity from right to left. 
So first step should be **decreasing value** of `P`, then **dereference** and then **increasing dereferenced value**, am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Precedence and evaluation have nothing to do with one another. Precendence determines the meaning of a sequence of source code (it's a part of the parsing rules). Evaluation is about establishing the value of an expression. You need to know first what something means before you can compute its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the precedence is

```
++(*(P--))
```

But note that the decrement is a postfix operation: even though the change to `P` happens first, the rest of the expression uses the old value of `P`.  So in your example, first `P` is decremented to `array+4`, but the value of `P--` is `array+5`, so `array[5]` gets incremented.

Answer (score 2):

You can imagine this expression

```
++*P--
```

the following way

```
int *tmp = p;
--p;
int value = *tmp;
++value;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello World";
    char *p = s + 6;

    std::printf( "%c\n", ++*p-- );
    std::printf( "%s\n", s );

    p = s + 6;
    char *tmp = p--;
    char value = *tmp;
    ++value;

    std::printf( "%c\n", value );
    std::printf( "%s\n", s );
}
```

The program output is

```
X
Hello Xorld
Y
Hello Xorld
```

The difference in the outputting the string is that expression `++*p--` changes the string itself but expression `++value;` changes a separate object. But the logic is similar.

Postfix expression `p--` has the highest priority but its value is the value of `p` before decreasing.

Unary operators ++ and * in expression `++*p--` group right to left. So at first operator * is applied to the expression and after that operator ++ is applied.